# How to access/read class instance attributes in octave?

Tags: class, oop, properties, octave, getter-setter

Making a class similar to that one in the [example](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Creating-a-Class.html) I attached arguments to the class instance like so

```
function t = train (m, F_z, F_b, varargin)
  ...
  t.m =     m;      % total mass of train [kg]
  t.F_z =  F_z;     % ...
  ...
  t = class (t, "train");
```

Getting the fieldnames works

```
>> t1 = train(100, 150000, 200000);
...
>> fieldnames(t1)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = m
  [2,1] = F_z
  ...
```

But how do I access these? Apparently it's not

```
>> t1.m
error: invalid index for class
>> getfield(t1, 'm')
error: invalid index for class
error: called from
...
```

If I leave out the line `t = class (t, 'train');` at the end of `function t = train (m...` in `@train/train.m` these things all seem to work fine... But then its a `struct` and not a `class`

Comment: If you want to access them with ".", you have to define it: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Defining-Indexing-And-Indexed-Assignment.html#Defining-Indexing-And-Indexed-Assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways. You can define a method to retrieve it (easy), or you set up `subsref` (subscript reference) (hard).

To define a method, simply create `@train/m.m` with:

```
function r = m ()
  r = t.m;
endfunction
```

To set up subscripting, then create `@train/subsref.m` with:

```
function r = subsref (val, idx)
  if (strcmp (idx.type, ".") && strcmp (idx.subs, "m"))
    r = val.m;
  endif
endfunction
```

This will allow you to access *only* the field `m`. To give access to any of the properties within your class, you can simply do:

```
function r = subsref (val, idx)
  r = subsref (struct (val), idx);
endfunction
```

To allow access to a subset of properties, you can:

```
function r = subsref (val, idx)
  if (strcmp (idx.type, ".") && any (strcmp (idx.subs, {"m", "f2", "F_z"})))
    r = val.(idx.subs{1});
  endif
endfunction
```

But `subsref` controls all indexing, not only when accessing it as a structure. You could allow people to index the object (maybe you have a wagon class, and indexing the train returns them). The function looks a bit weird at start (just like `subsasgn` (subscript assignment)) but can be quite useful. You could do:

```
function r = subsref (val, idx)
  if (strcmp (idx.type, ".") && strcmp (idx.subs, "m"))
    r = val.m;
  elseif (strcmp (idx.type, "()"))
    r = val.wagons(idx.subs{:});
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3):

One quick and dirty way is to break the OOP philosophy in octave. NO need to define `subsref` or `getter` methods. To access the fields, just transform the object into a `struct` as

```
>> t1 = train(100, 150000, 200000);
>> t1_easy = struct(t1);
>> t1_easy.m
>> t1_easy.F_z
```